# Azure App Service Always On vs what is logged

Tags: azure, iis, logging, azure-web-app-service

Why does Azure App Service Always On make two requests, one to my site ZZTESTSITE and second to ~1ZZTESTSITE? What is the Service Name preceded with tilde in the first request?

```
2017-06-20 17:17:02 ~1ZZTESTSITE GET / - 80 - 100.89.142.31 AlwaysOn - - zztestsite.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2945 451 15
2017-06-20 17:17:02 ZZTESTSITE GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=743965b6-d3e2-42b9-9353-7772f9fbc898 80 - ::1 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=b5289afa9cd711b67c1fe9137a6e3ff232f80bd3fa1bd96e9fc89992472b4e57 - zztestsite.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 11433 652 15
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every App Service actually has two sites:

1. The main site where your site runs
2. The 'scm' site that runs Kudu (which includes WebJobs support), as well as things like msdeploy.

Always On keeps both of them awake, and The ~1 name refers to ping requests made to the scm site.

Comment: Shouldn't the SCM site have ".scm" as part of its hostname?